DAX calculate relatively last month, quarter and year
I need to create 3 measures for distinct count of MerchantName in DimMerchant for last month, last 3 months, and last year of a given relative date.
Example:
For DateValue = 4/1/2024 (date type MMddyyyy)
LM: count of merchants in 3/1/2024
L3M: count of merchants in 3/1/2024, 2/1/2024 and 1/1/2024
LY: count of merchants between 3/1/2024 and 4/1/2024

MerchantInternal# measure (current attempt):
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('DimMerchant'[MerchantName]),
    FactTransaction
)

Table relationships:

Merchant one to many to FactTransaction on MerchantName
DimDate one to many to FactTransaction on DatePK


Example data input for testing:

DimDate (one to many to FactTransaction on DatePK)




DatePK
DateValue
Year
Month




20230901
9/1/2023
2023
9


20231001
10/1/2023
2023
10


20231101
11/1/2023
2023
11


20231201
12/1/2023
2023
12


20240101
1/1/2024
2024
1


20240201
2/1/2024
2024
2


20240301
3/1/2024
2024
3


20240401
4/1/2024
2024
4


20240501
5/1/2024
2024
5




DimMerchant (one to many to FactTransaction on MerchantHK)




MerchantHK
MerchantName




AAA
NAAA


AAA
NAAA


BBB
NBBB


DDD
NDDD


BBB
NBBB


DDD
NDDD


CCC
MCCC


DDD
MDDD


BBB
MBBB




FactTransaction (Main fact table where DimDate and DimMerchant have relationship)




DatePK
MerchantHK




20230901
AAA


20231001
AAA


20231101
BBB


20231201
DDD


20240101
BBB


20240201
DDD


20240301
CCC


20240401
DDD


20240501
BBB




Can you provide the data set corresponding to the data model you have ?

@AmiraBedhiafi, thank you for spotting. Added sample data for 3 tables DimMerchant, DimMerchant and FactTransaction.

Do have a look at the DAX Time intelligence functions.
Here is an example of what your measures could look like:
// base measure
# Merchant =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(DimMerchant[MerchantHK]),
    FactTransaction
  )

// Last Month or Previous Month
# Merchant LM = CALCULATE([# Merchant], PREVIOUSMONTH(DimDate[DateValue]))

// Last 3 months (not including current selected month)
# Merchant L3M =
  CALCULATE(
    [# Merchant],
    DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[DateValue], MAX(DimDate[DateValue]) - 1, -3, MONTH)
  )

// Last 12 months (not including current selected month)
# Merchant LY =
  CALCULATE(
    [# Merchant],
    DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[DateValue], MAX(DimDate[DateValue]) - 1, -12, MONTH)
  )


Hi Sam, thank you for the solution. It works :)
Marking it shortly as answered, but have 1 more question (Not a DAX expert). In case I also need to calculate that the merchant's first transaction is in the given year (i.e.: for 202403, get me merchants that had their first transaction in 2024 and then count accordingly lm , l3m, l12m.
I am trying with:
CALCULATE(
[MerchantInternal#],
YEAR(MIN(DimDate[DateValue])) = YEAR(DimDate[DateValue]),
DATESINPERIOD(DimDate[DateValue], MAX(DimDate[DateValue]), -12, MONTH)
)
But seems it is not fully correct.
